# Error when build released APK with flutter in android studio

Tags: gradle, flutter

i can build a debug apk without any problem, and also i try my app on three mobile device without any error, but when i try to build released apk, i faced this error:

```
D:\mis>flutter build apk
Initializing gradle...                                           1.0s
Resolving dependencies...                                        4.5s
Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-annotations' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support.test:monitor:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support:support-annota
tions:27.1.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support
:support-annotations:27.1.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.
1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations
:25.3.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:2
5.3.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3
.1'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1

   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2
         project :app > com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2 > com.android.support.test:monitor:1.0.2
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-annotations' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support.test:monitor:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support:support-annota
tions:27.1.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support
:support-annotations:27.1.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.
1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations
:25.3.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:2
5.3.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3
.1'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1

   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
         project :app > com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
         project :app > com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
         project :app > com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-annotations' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support.test:monitor:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support:support-annota
tions:27.1.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support
:support-annotations:27.1.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.
1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations
:25.3.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:2
5.3.1'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.alveliu.flutterfullpdfviewer:flutter_full_pdf_viewer:1.0.0' --> 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' --> 'com
.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3
.1'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '25.3.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses vers
ion 25.3.1


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
 6.4s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

i download a new Gradle, but still same problem?

this is my build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.mis"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

   signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

i cannot know from where this problem? and how can try to solve it? it is from Gradle? or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

in `android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: It needs to be under inside android section and not in the root. You should mention this in the response IMHO.